# How to map left CTRL key to win key on external keyboard?

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard, windows

I have an external keyboard (Wired microsoft 200 if it metters).
The current status is that the win key (between left CTRL and the left ALT) can be used for copy paste. WIN + C, WIN + V does copy and paste. I want the same functionality for the left CTRL.

This is what I want:
[image]

I've tried changing it on the keyboard settings, but you can't choose another key on the keyboard for it:
[image]

I've tried to add shortcuts:
[image]

But it doesn't work well - it demands to re-configure in additional applications.

I had a more sophisticated keyboard before, and I could just map left CTRL to win, as showed in the first image.
This way every press on the left CTRL is the same as pressing WIN, and that's what I want.

Is there any way to do so? Some external software that allows it? Thanks

Comment: The Win key is interpreted as  Cmd ⌘ on Mac. Do you mean you want to also map Ctrl to Cmd? This can be done in the first image, but would in effect remove your Control key entirely. To change only one side but not the other you'd need something like Karabiner.

Comment: Karabiner is exactly what I needed. Thanks!
(if you want to add an answer and I'll accept it)